# IE9 Beta Support for localStorage

Tags: local-storage, internet-explorer-9

Does anyone know if current IE9 Beta fully supports HTML5 "localStorage" functionality?
Normally the test for "localStorage" support can be done with js code just like:

```
try {
    return  ('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null;
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

Well, it seems that this kind of test returns "true" but if you try something like:

```
localStorage.removeItem ('key')
```

you get an error on the Javascript Console (SCRIPT16389 error). Any more info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely sure what the problem here is, because `localstorage` has been functional in IE since version **8**. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062%28VS.85%29.aspx
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html

And also, this working example I whipped up: http://jsbin.com/ijega3/edit

Answer (score 3):

The reason your test returns true is that the statement: `window['localStorage']` returns "undefined". Change your test to: `window['localStorage'] != null` (or `!= undefined`) and it will return false.

My version (9.0.8112.16421IC) of IE9 does not seem to support `localStorage` either.

Comment: The `'localStorage' in window` test always passes for IE9 but `window['localStorage'] != null` will only pass for real domains, not local file URLs etc.

Comment: In fact it gives differents result for `window['localStorage'] != null` and `window['localStorage'] !== null`. `!=` or `!==` with `undefined` is consistent though.

Answer (score 1):

There was a regression with removeItem in IE9 beta.

A bug was filed on the Connect bug reporting database. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/613497/web-storage-remove-method-not-working-according-to-the-spec

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on [Comparison of layout engines (HTML5) on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29) Web Storage should be supported.

PS: IE9 is Trident 5.0. (thanks *EricLaw -MSFT-* for the mistake).